# How to allow some special characters and how to insert them into MySQL using PHP pdo

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

I've been having issue allowing some special characters and when inserting them into database they are showing up incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your DB charset is set to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Comment: How do I change that?